# Adding std::fstream is introducing Linker error error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2017

I've a DLL (VC++ VS2017), which compiles perfcetly fine & also runs fine.

It has the /MD (dynamic linking of C runtime settings) as can be seen in the snapshot here:
[image]
Now I decided to

Now it all compiles, links & runs fine till here. But if i introduce **std::fstream** as below,

```
#include <fstream>
std::fstream file2("C:\\afile.txt", std::ios::app);
```

it introduces the below linker error:

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in ABCSrc.obj
```

I'm wondering how come adding fstream is introducing this error.

**My RunTime value is "Dynamic /MD) as can be seen in snapshot attached, but not sure why is it s showing this error. How do i fix it.**

Comment: *Where* do you "introduce std::fstream"? In the DLL? In an application using the DLL? Is it the DLL that doesn't build anymore?

Comment: Seems like some objects have a static runtime, find it and fix it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, its a DLL. Sorry i missed to mention about this.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Thinks work fine before introducing fstream. And wondering how come introducing fstream is causing this issue. If "some objects had a static runtime", this issue should have popped up even without fstream right ? But it works absolutely fine before introducing fstream.

Comment: (1) Can you reduce the dll code to something you can paste here, that still shows this phenomena?  (2) Can you please activate /VERBOSE (project properties/ linker / general / show progress), and dump the output here?